# Запятые перед "и"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

В рамках заседания большое внимание было уделено грядущему введению в учебный процесс новых учебных планов и подготовке в связи с этим откорректированных и новых учебных программ и учебно-методических комплексов, составлению индивидуальных планов сотрудников, организации работы кафедр института.

Перед каким союзом **И** надо поставить запятую?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Очень длинное предложение, а запятых перед **и** ставить не надо. Здесь разные группы однородных членов:

1) уделено — чему? — введению и подготовке, составлению, организации;
2) подготовке — чего? — программ и комплексов;
3) программ — каких? — откорректированных и новых.